# Why writing to stdin of subprocess is not working when stdin is taken to variable?

Tags: rust

I want to communicate with dart language sever process. Currently i'm experimenting with it and i don't understand one think. I made 2 very simple implementations which in my opinion should work exactly the same but one of them works and second doesn't. Could someone describe me why?

First implementation that i tried is:

```rust
use std::{process::Stdio, time::Duration};

use tokio::{io::AsyncWriteExt, process::Command, time::sleep};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut process = Command::new("dart")
        .args([
            "language-server",
            "--protocol=analyzer",
            "--protocol-traffic-log=logs.txt",
        ])
        .stdin(Stdio::piped())
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .stderr(Stdio::piped())
        .kill_on_drop(true)
        .spawn()
        .expect("failed to spawn process");

    process
        .stdin
        .take()
        .unwrap()
        .write_all(b"test")
        .await
        .unwrap();
    sleep(Duration::from_secs(5)).await;
}
```

And the log.txt look like this (I know input is invalid but important thing is that server received message):

```
1673866099379:Ver:1645600465579221612245:unknown.client.classic:unknown:1.33.1:2.18.0
1673866099410:Noti:{"event"::"server.connected","params"::{"version"::"1.33.1","pid"::16810}}
1673866099421:Req:test
1673866099422:Res:{"id"::"","error"::{"code"::"INVALID_REQUEST","message"::"Invalid request"}}
```

Second implementation look like this. The only difference is that I store `process.stdin.take().unwrap()` in variable.

```rust
use std::{process::Stdio, time::Duration};

use tokio::{io::AsyncWriteExt, process::Command, time::sleep};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut process = Command::new("dart")
        .args([
            "language-server",
            "--protocol=analyzer",
            "--protocol-traffic-log=logs.txt",
        ])
        .stdin(Stdio::piped())
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .stderr(Stdio::piped())
        .kill_on_drop(true)
        .spawn()
        .expect("failed to spawn process");

    let mut stdin = process.stdin.take().unwrap();

    stdin.write_all(b"Test").await.unwrap();

    sleep(Duration::from_secs(5)).await;
}
```

log.txt

```
1673866343914:Ver:1645600465579221612245:unknown.client.classic:unknown:1.33.1:2.18.0
1673866343942:Noti:{"event"::"server.connected","params"::{"version"::"1.33.1","pid"::16966}}
```

Comment: Can you share what happens if you include `\n` by the end of the input provided, in both cases?

Comment: @E_net4thecommentflagger That worked. I can't believe I didn't come up with that :P But thank you very much. 
I just make some some tests and it look like first is working without `\n` because stdin is dropped just after calling `write_all` because it's not saved to variable. When i added `mem::drop(stdin)` in second after `write_all` it worked too.

Comment: You should answer your own question :)